Finding a open subset of a open set whose closure is also contained in the open set
This may be dumb, but I am trying to prove the following statement.
Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. For every $U\in\mathcal{T}$, for every $x\in U$, there exists $V\in\mathcal{T}$ such that $x\in V$ and $\overline{V}\subseteq U$.
I am reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and his proposition for $3.9$. He had the following claim: "Let $B$ be a neighbourhood of $p$ such that $\overline{B}\subseteq U$." I am wondering why such a choice is always possible.

This is not true for a general topological space. You are reading Smooth Manifolds, are we assuming our space to be a topological manifold? Do we have any other assumptions?

Assuming that your space $X$ satisfies the $T_1$ axiom (i.e., finite sets are closed), your condition is equivalent to regularity (and not all spaces are regular; take for example any space that is not Hausdorff). A $T_1$ space is said to be regular if for every point $x \in X$ and every closed set $C \subseteq X$ that misses $x$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ disjoint from an open set $V$ containing $C$.
In the following, we assume $X$ is $T_1$.
To show that regularity implies your condition, let $x \in X$ be arbitrary, and $U \subseteq X$ an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Then take $C = X - U$, which is a closed set that misses $x$. By hypothesis, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ disjoint from an open set $W$ containing $X - U$. Then ${\rm Cl} V \subseteq U$. (If not, take $y \in {\rm Cl} V \cap (X - U)$. Observe that $y \in X - U \implies y \in W$, which means $W$ intersects $V$, a contradiction.)
To show that your condition implies regularity, let $x \in X$ be arbitrary, and $C \subseteq X$ be an arbitrary closed set missing $X$. Then $U = X - C$ is a neighborhood of $x$. By hypothesis, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that ${\rm Cl} V \subseteq U$. Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $X - {\rm Cl} V$, which is an open set containing $C$.

In your "condition implies regularity", I fail to see any hints why "finite sets are closed" follows. In fact, I think it doesn't (just take the product of a regular space and in infinite indiscrete space)

In your second paragraph, can’t it happen that $y\in$ClV\V ?

@HagenvonEitzen You are correct. The space should be assumed to be $T_1$. I will update my answer.

@FedePoncio It could be, but that doesn't matter. Since $X - U \subseteq W$, then $y \in W$, but since $y \in {\rm Cl} V$, any neighborhood of $y$ (including $W$) intersects $V$, which leads to the contradiction.

I don't understand this $T_1$-issue: the condition in the question is exactly regularity, no matter whether the space is $T_1$ or not.  @Hagen von Eitzen: the condition is obviously hereditarily, hence your example doesn't fulfill it. No $T_1$ is needed!

@Ulli The definition of "regular space" I am using includes that points be topologically distinguishable (i.e., I am considering "regular" as a synonym of $T_3$). Sure, if that piece of the definition is dropped, then it would indeed be equivalent to the condition. An even simpler example is the space $X = {0, 1}$, with topology $\mathcal{T} = {\emptyset, X}$. It satisfies the condition, but is not "regular" (under the definition I am using), but is regular under your definition.

@K. Jiang: yes, this is quite common. But as I learned, at MSE, regular does not include $T_1$. And IMO, it's very useful to have a name for "regular without $T_1$".

This is in fact not always true. Take as a counterexample the space consisting of two points $\{p, l\}$ with opens $\{\emptyset, \{l\}, \{p, l\}\}$.
Take $x = l$ and $U = \{l\}$. Then the only open $V\subset U$ that contains $x$ is $l$ itself, but this has closure $\{p, l\}$ which is outside of $U$.
You need a separation axiom to be able to draw this conclusion.
I believe you need that the topological space $X$ is regular. This means that any point $x$ and any closed set $S\subset X$ that doesn't contain $x$ can be separated by open neighborhoods. In other words there exist opens $U_x$ and $U_S$ such that $U_x \cap U_S = \emptyset$ and $x\in U_x$ and $S\subset U_S$.
Do you see how to prove the required result given that $X$ is regular?
